# Do we still need to write the empty angle brackets when using transparent std function objects?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

With class template argument deduction we can write:

```
std::less Fn;
```

However, G++ 8.2 rejects this code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
std::vector v= { 1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 4 };

std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),std::greater());
}
```

emitting the following error:

```
error: cannot deduce template arguments for 'greater' from ()
```

Clang++ 7.0 and MSVC 15.8.0 compile it without warnings. Which compiler is right?

Comment: interesting gcc compiles with `std::greater{}`

Comment: What is *"G++"*? GCC?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes [tag:g++] is the c++ compiler of GCC

Answer (score 28, accepted):

GCC is wrong. There is already a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81486).

[[dcl.type.simple]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#2) says:

> A *type-specifier* of the form `typename`<sub>*opt*</sub> *nested-name-specifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> *template-name* is a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).

And [[dcl.type.class.deduct]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct#2) says:

> A placeholder for a deduced class type can also be used in the *type-specifier-seq* in the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a *new-expression*, **as the *simple-type-specifier* in an explicit type conversion (functional notation)** ([expr.type.conv]), or as the *type-specifier* in the *parameter-declaration* of a *template-parameter*. A placeholder for a deduced class type shall not appear in any other context.

Such use is allowed.

---

[[temp.arg]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg#4) describes the **syntax error** that a *template-id* is required but there is no `<>`. However here `std::greater` is not resolved as a *template-id* so that paragraph does not apply.

Comment: Is this case an explicit type conversion (functional notation)?

Comment: @metalfox Isn't it? [\[expr.type.conv\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#1): "A simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by a parenthesized optional expression-list or by a braced-init-list (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer. If the type is a placeholder for a deduced class type, it is replaced by the return type of the function selected by overload resolution for class template deduction for the remainder of this subclause."

Comment: I see. I didn't think of it as a type conversion

Answer (score 14):

Clang and MSVC are correct. This should be well-formed because of the combination effect of [implicitly-generated deduction guides (since C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Implicitly-generated_deduction_guides) and default template argument.

(emphasis mine)

> When a function-style cast or declaration of a variable uses the name
>   of a primary class template C without an argument list as the type
>   specifier, deduction will proceed as follows:
>
> - If C is defined, for each constructor (or constructor template) Ci declared in the named primary template (if it is defined), a fictional
>     function template Fi, is constructed, such that
>
>   - template parameters of Fi are the template parameters of C followed (if Ci is a constructor template) by the template parameters
>       of Ci (**default template arguments are included too**)
>   - the function parameters of Fi are the constructor parameters
>   - the return type of Fi is C followed by the template parameters of the class template enclosed in <>
> - **If C is not defined or does not declare any constructors, an additional fictional function template is added, derived as above from
>     a hypothetical constructor C()**
> - In any case, an additional fictional function template derived as above from a hypothetical constructor C(C) is added, called the copy
>     deduction candidate.
>
> Template argument deduction and overload resolution is then performed
>   for initialization of a fictional object of hypothetical class type,
>   whose constructor signatures match the guides (except for return type)
>   for the purpose of forming an overload set, and the initializer is
>   provided by the context in which class template argument deduction was
>   performed, except that the first phase of list-initialization
>   (considering initializer-list constructors) is omitted if the
>   initializer list consists of a single expression of type (possibly
>   cv-qualified) U, where U is a specialization of C or a class derived
>   from a specialization of C.
>
> These fictional constructors are public members of the hypothetical
>   class type. They are explicit if the guide was formed from an explicit
>   constructor. If overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed.
>   Otherwise, the return type of the selected F template specialization
>   becomes the deduced class template specialization.

Given `std::greater()`, the implicitly-generated deduction guide is applied and the additional fictional function is selected at last. As the result of overload resolution the default argument `void` is applied, then the deduced type will be `void`. That means `std::greater()` should be same as writing `std::greater<void>()` or `std::greater<>()`.

---

<sup>BTW: Gcc doesn't compile with `std::greater()`, but `std::greater{}` or `std::greater g;` are fine, it might be gcc's bug.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure... `std::less L` compiles just fine. It is even shown as an example in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: @songyuanyao you are right. cppreference doesn't show neither a ctor, nor a deduction guide. Haven't checked the standard.